# YelpSharp returns error "Additional information: No OAuth info available."

Tags: c#, yelp

I am using @JustinBeckwith's project [YelpSharp](https://github.com/JustinBeckwith/YelpSharp). I have the config file and I have edited it with my own Yelp API keys. I actually have not wrote a single line of code yet - I am using the tests included with YelpSharp.

Using VS2013 on Windows 7 x64.

Unfortunately when I try to run his (Justin's) tests I run into the error mentioned in the title:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in     
BusinessResearcher.exe

Additional information: No OAuth info available.  Please modify 
Config.cs to add your YELP API OAuth keys
```

Here (or [here](https://github.com/JustinBeckwith/YelpSharp/blob/master/YelpSharpTests/Config.cs) - the code is the same as the original) is my config file (I have edited out my keys):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using YelpSharp;

namespace BusinessResearcher
{
    class Config
    {
        private static Options _options;

        /// <summary>
        /// return the oauth options for using the Yelp API.  I store my keys in the environment settings, but you
        /// can just write them out here, or put them into an app.config file.  For more info, visit
        /// http://www.yelp.com/developers/getting_started/api_access
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Options Options
        {
            get
            {
                if (_options == null)
                {
                    // get all of the options out of EnvironmentSettings.  You can easily just put your own keys in here without
                    // doing the env dance, if you so choose
                    _options = new Options()
                    {
                        AccessToken = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("my_code_is_hidden_here_from_stackoverflow", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User),
                        AccessTokenSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("my_code_is_hidden_here_from_stackoverflow", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User),
                        ConsumerKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("my_code_is_hidden_here_from_stackoverflow", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User),
                        ConsumerSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("my_code_is_hidden_here_from_stackoverflow", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User)
                    };

                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_options.AccessToken) ||
                        String.IsNullOrEmpty(_options.AccessTokenSecret) ||
                        String.IsNullOrEmpty(_options.ConsumerKey) ||
                        String.IsNullOrEmpty(_options.ConsumerSecret))
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("No OAuth info available.  Please modify Config.cs to add your YELP API OAuth keys");
                    }
                }
                  return _options;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the method from my `Form1.cs` button(click event):

```
        Yelp y = new Yelp(Config.Options);
        var task = y.Search("coffee", "seattle, wa").ContinueWith((searchResults) =>
        {
            foreach (var business in searchResults.Result.businesses)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(business.name);
            }
        });
```

Comment: You are missing 4 environment vars (`my_code_is_hidden_here`) that contain your keys and secrets.

Comment: @rene, I have mentioned that I have edited my keys out.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint at the line `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty ` you have to check which of the members of `_options` is empty. You only talk about config files. I didn't know you updated and created those environment vars as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

@JustinBeckwith has said that you can put your own keys "without doing the env dance", but I was not sure how to do it. I tried to type it in as a variable, but it kept saying that `, is expected`. Apparently I have to add them all on one line.

To solve it change this (from config.cs):

```
                AccessToken = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("6iIPqqCxpUTflkTyjBKb0rtUPbnW-z8l", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User),
                AccessTokenSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("rxA6_mwQwCFjqYoOajs566e8UUw", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User),
                ConsumerKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("40o625RXM9Cylazmjx8F1A", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User),
                ConsumerSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UfOwDu-qRbCLHJFaQ83xEf1Hbgg", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User)
```

with this:

```
AccessToken = "access_token_here", AccessTokenSecret = "AccessTokenSecret_key", ConsumerKey = "ConsumerKey_key", ConsumerSecret = "ConsumerSecret_key",};
```